# How was the 747 in the China Airlines Flight 006 affected by the wing damage it sustained?

Tags: boeing-747, incidents, china

The passengers on [China Airlines Flight 006](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/China_Airlines_Flight_006) had a very memorable flight when the crew lost control and the aeroplane went into a high-speed dive.

Various pieces of the aircraft were torn off. The plane was repaired and returned to service, with its wings bent permanently upwards by 5cm.

How did this permanent damage affect it afterwards? Did it fly or perform noticeably differently? Did it require a special inspection regime for the rest of its operating life?

Comment: If a dimension has permanently changed, it means the metal has "yielded", or stretched beyond its elastic limit (like when you over stretch a spring and it's longer than originally, and cantilever metal structures are big springs).  The part that's yielded isn't as strong as before.  Perhaps they did a "geometry shoot" where the overall dimensions are measured and the deformation was still within specification and decided it was ok as is, but I would have expected the yielded components to have been replaced.  We don't know the details of the repair so there's no way to know for sure.

Comment: The additional dihedral probably made it more stable...

Comment: ... and jauntier.

Comment: @JohnK Aluminium alloys are not necessarily weaker after stretching, as may be found in [this doc](https://digitalcommons.lmu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1000&context=mech_fac)

Comment: Wings flex quite a bit in flight, much more than 5cm, so I doubt that it had any special handling characteristics.

Comment: The linked article said the wings were bent upwards after the accident. It does not say that the damage was not repaired. The actual report says "the set was within the manufacturer's allowable tolerances" but again does not say if the damage was repaired.

Comment: @user71659 If something is "permanently bent" I think that implies that it stayed that way.

Comment: @DanieleProcida So they replaced the whole wing...

Comment: It also depends where they measured those 5cm...

Comment: @DanieleProcida  Actually mulling it over I would think that on a plane that big that a 5cm deviation from datum at the wing tip (it would be based on the airplane on jacks and fully defueled, allowing for the wing sagging under its own weight) was well within Boeing's geometry specs and it may have been that way when it left the factory. If it was in spec when they shot it, they're good to go aside from fixing other obvious damage.

Comment: In case anyone is wondering where the aircraft is now: https://www.747sp.com/747sp-production-list/22805-564/

Answer (score 1):

As you know the aircraft manufacturers keep tracking their aircrafts because any accident of these would damage their reputation. All automatic data transmissions are traced by the manufacturer whether the operator has a tracking contract with the manufacturer or not. Should it had an asymmetrical behavior causing any dangerous consequences the manufacturer would have made what is necessary to ground it.

In the website you refer to, it is written « After repairs were made to the plane, it returned to service on 25 April 1985. It continued in service for nearly 12 years »:

I may assume this aircraft has landed in Europe, or in USA, should it have been dangerous, it would have been grounded.

As far economical performances are concerned, that’s secondary compared to safety, it is the operator decision to evaluate to make it fly or not if it becomes less economical.

Comment: Were automatic data transmissions a thing in the 1980s?

Comment: These are ACARS messages, automatic maintenance data started in the mid 80’s , but this aircraft resumed flying in 1985 for 12 years with the same operator  and even continued flying after that for some more years. Further Boeing has its own means to trace these problems